# Angular CRUD: when I update the information I cannot do a new update because the update button disappears

Tags: angular, hibernate

I have a little problem that I'm not being able to solve.

If I update the customer information in the detail list and click on the Update button it works correctly; However, if I want to update the information of both the same customer and some other customer again, I can't do it because the update button disappears and I only have the close button left.

How can I solve this problem?

This is my code:

**customer-list.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from '../customer.service';
import { Customer } from '../customer';
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-list',
  templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {
  editProfileForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private customerservice: CustomerService, private fb: FormBuilder, private modalService: NgbModal) {} 

  customersArray: any[] = [];
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  customers: Customer[] = [];
  customer: Customer = new Customer();
  deleteMessage = false;
  customerlist: any;
  isupdated = false;
  isUpdating = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerservice.getCustomerList().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.customers = data;
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    })
    this.editProfileForm = this.fb.group({
      customercode: [''],
      surname: [''],
      name: ['']
     });
  }

  openModal(targetModal: any, customer: any) {
    this.modalService.open(targetModal, {
     centered: true,
     backdrop: 'static'
    });
   
    this.editProfileForm!.patchValue({
     customercode:customer.customercode, 
     surname:customer.surname,
     name:customer.name,
     });
    /** console.log('name STUDENT IS:' , customer.customer_name); */
   }

   onSubmit() {
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
    console.log("res:", this.editProfileForm!.getRawValue());
   }

  deleteCustomer(id: any) {
    this.customerservice.deleteCustomer(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.deleteMessage = true;
          this.customerservice.getCustomerList().subscribe(data => {
            this.customers = data
          })
        },
        error => console.log(error));
  }

  updateCustomer(id: any) {
    console.log('Update button clicked!');
    this.customerservice.getCustomer(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('returned data: ', data);
          this.customerlist = data;
          this.isUpdating = true;
          this.isupdated = false;

        },
        error => console.log(error));
  }

  customerupdateform = new FormGroup({
    customercode: new FormControl(),
    surname: new FormControl(),
    name: new FormControl(),
    });

  updateCust() {
    this.customer = new Customer();
    this.customer.customercode = this.editProfileForm.get('customercode')!.value;
    this.customer.surname = this.editProfileForm.get('surname')!.value;
    this.customer.name = this.editProfileForm.get('name')!.value;
    console.log(this.customer);

    this.customerservice.updateCustomer(this.customer.customercode!,this.customer).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.isupdated = true;
        this.isUpdating = false;
        this.customerservice.getCustomerList().subscribe(data => {
          this.customers = data
          this.modalService.dismissAll();
          console.log("res:", this.editProfileForm!.getRawValue());
        })
      },
      error => console.log(error));
  }

  get Surname() {
    return this.customerupdateform.get('surname');
  }

  get Name() {
    return this.customerupdateform.get('name');
  }

  changeisUpdate() {
    this.isupdated = false;
    this.isUpdating = false;
  }
}
```

**customer-list.component.html**

```js
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h1 style="text-align: center">Clienti</h1><br>
      <div class="row" [hidden]="!deleteMessage">
  
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <strong>Customer Data Deleted</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th>Customer Code</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
  
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
            <td>{{customer.customercode}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.surname}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
            <td><button (click)="deleteCustomer(customer.customercode)" class='btn btn-primary'><i
                  class="fa fa-futboll-0">Delete</i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(editProfileModal, customer)" >Update</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody><br>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <ng-template #editProfileModal let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="editProfileLabel">Edit Profile</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" (click)="modal.dismiss()" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
    </div>
  
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form [formGroup]="editProfileForm" (ngSubmit)="updateCust()">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="customercode" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Codice fiscale</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="customercode" id="customercode">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="surname" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Surname</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="surname" id="surname">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" id="name">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [hidden]="isupdated">Confirm update</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Close</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are hiding it on purpose after successful update on form submit. In this function

```
updateCust() {
 ...  
 this.customerservice.updateCustomer(this.customer.customercode!,this.customer).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.isupdated = true;
        ...
 })
}
```

You need to keep `this.isupdated` false all the time if you need to enable update button because it has [hidden] property binded with this variable.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [hidden]="isupdated">Confirm update</button>
```